# Unity Shaderlab- transform from screen space to world space

Tags: c#, matrix, unity-game-engine, camera, shaderlab

I'm making a post-processing shader (in unity) that requires world-space coordinates. I have access to the depth information of a certain pixel, as well as the onscreen location of that pixel. How can I find the world position that that pixel corresponds to, much like the function ViewportToWorldPos()?

Comment: Check out the 'Slices via World Space Position' example here (scroll down): https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I want. I'm using a post-processing shader.

Comment: OK try here: http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/08/screen-shaders-and-postprocessing-effects-in-unity3d/ You know about search engines, right?

Comment: I do know about search engines. This article isn't really helpful to me, as I already know how to do post-processing shaders in general. I need help with this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's been three years! I was working on this recently, and an older engineer help me solved the problem. Here is the code.

1. We need to firstly give a camera transform matrix to the shader in script:

   ```cs
   void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dst)
   {
       Camera curruntCamera = Camera.main;
       Matrix4x4 matrixCameraToWorld = currentCamera.cameraToWorldMatrix;
       Matrix4x4 matrixProjectionInverse = GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix(currentCamera.projectionMatrix, false).inverse;
       Matrix4x4 matrixHClipToWorld = matrixCameraToWorld * matrixProjectionInverse;

       Shader.SetGlobalMatrix("_MatrixHClipToWorld", matrixHClipToWorld);
       Graphics.Blit(src, dst, _material);
   }
   ```
2. Then we need the depth information to transform the clip pos. Like this:

   ```cs
   inline half3 TransformUVToWorldPos(half2 uv)
   {
       half depth = tex2D(_CameraDepthTexture, uv).r;
       #ifndef SHADER_API_GLCORE
           half4 positionCS = half4(uv * 2 - 1, depth, 1) * LinearEyeDepth(depth);
       #else
           half4 positionCS = half4(uv * 2 - 1, depth * 2 - 1, 1) * LinearEyeDepth(depth);
       #endif
       return mul(_MatrixHClipToWorld, positionCS).xyz;
   }
   ```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this tutorial: http://flafla2.github.io/2016/10/01/raymarching.html

essentially:

- store one vector per corner of the screen, passed as constants, that goes from the camera position to said corner.
- interpolate the vectors based on the screen space position, or the uvs of your screenspace quad
- compute final position as **cameraPosition + interpolatedVector * depth**